# How to deserialize &str struct field from JSON in Rust

Tags: json, string, serialization, deserialization, rust

I'm deserializing a struct from JSON:

```
fn main() {
  let raw_json = r#"{"error": {"msg": "I am an error message"}}"#;
  let error: Error = json::decode(raw_json).unwrap();

}

struct Error {
  message: &'static str
}

impl<D: Decoder<E>, E> Decodable<D, E> for Error {
  fn decode(d: &mut D) -> Result<Error, E> {
    d.read_struct("error", 1, |d| {
      Ok(Error{
        message: try!(d.read_struct_field("msg", 0u, |d| Decodable::decode(d)))
      })
    })
  }
}
```

But getting this error:

`failed to find an implementation of trait serialize::serialize::Decodable<D,E> for &'static str`

Adding lifetime to `message` does not help. 
Turns out there is no implementation of `Decodable` trait for `&str`, but only for [String](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/385c39a77b238df9371ee8bccc768b8d39258edd/src/libserialize/serialize.rs#L311)

How do I deserialize my JSON into `&str` struct field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References can't be serialized or deserialized. A different approach is needed.

Your Error struct contains a `&'static str`. This means you could also represent errors in the form of an enum, which can be serialized. Then you could implement Show for Error.

```
extern crate serialize;
use serialize::{Decodable, Encodable};
use std::fmt;

#[deriving(Encodable, Decodable)]
enum Error {
    Foo,
    Bar
}

impl fmt::Show for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Foo => write!(f, "Foo happened"),
            Bar => write!(f, "Bar happened"),
        }
    }
}
```

The question is whether this is actually what you wanted. If you want the ability to represent an arbitrary error message (rather than a specific error type) then you'll have to use String.

```
extern crate serialize;
use serialize::{Decodable, Encodable};

#[deriving(Encodable, Decodable)]
struct Error {
    msg: String
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `&'static str`, you must have a string literal, a string that lasts for lifetime of the entire process (a.k.a. forever). This evidently can’t be achieved.

For `&'a str` in general, something else must be owning the bytes—it is a reference to some of the contents of a `String`, in general (it might also be `Vec<Ascii>` or possibly another similar UTF-8 string type outside the standard library). This is not the way in which the serialization works—there is not necessarily a value stored anywhere permanent, so it can’t produce references. This is why it’s only implemented for `String`: you simply cannot have it for `&str`.

Comment: Thanks for this. My all problems stem from lack of understanding between str and String. Now finally I think I get it. String is the place where the actual string is stored, while &str is just a view on it. With literals, &str is just a view on a literal. So we can't deserialize the view, we can only do it for the real storage.